# Empty zeroth element in array/list to eliminate repeated decrementing. Does this improve performance?

Tags: python, arrays, performance

I am using Python to solve Project Euler problems. Many require caching the results of past calculations to improve performance, leading to code like this:

```
pastResults = [None] * 1000000
def someCalculation(integerArgument):
    # return result of a calculation performed on numberArgument
    # for example, summing the factorial or square of its digits
for eachNumber in range(1, 1000001)
    if pastResults[eachNumber - 1] is None:
        pastResults[eachNumber - 1] = someCalculation(eachNumber)
        # perform additional actions with pastResults[eachNumber - 1]
```

Would the repeated decrementing have an adverse impact on program performance? Would having an empty or dummy zeroth element (so the zero-based array emulates a one-based array) improve performance by eliminating the repeated decrementing?

```
pastResults = [None] * 1000001
def someCalculation(integerArgument):
    # return result of a calculation performed on numberArgument
    # for example, summing the factorial or square of its digits
for eachNumber in range(1, 1000001)
    if pastResults[eachNumber] is None:
        pastResults[eachNumber] = someCalculation(eachNumber)
        # perform additional actions with pastResults[eachNumber]
```

I also feel that emulating a one-based array would make the code easier to follow. That is why I do not make the range zero-based with `for eachNumber in range(1000000)` as `someCalculation(eachNumber + 1)` would not be logical.

How significant is the additional memory from the empty zeroth element? What other factors should I consider? I would prefer answers that are not confined to Python and Project Euler.

EDIT: Should be `is None` instead of `is not None`.

Comment: Obligatory comment: Have you tried profiling to see if it's a bottleneck?

Comment: `I also feel that emulating a one-based array would make the code easier to follow` a much better reason than perf concerns. On the other hand, you will indeed save the decrement at the expense of 1 millionth more memory.

Comment: Should `is not None` be `is None` instead? That is, is it supposed to be calculating values that were previously missing, or is it updating ones that already exist (and skipping ones that are `None`)? In the former case, if each value depends on the ones before it (as with factorials or values in a Fibonacci sequence), you might do better if you started with an empty list (or nearly empty), then appended new values to the end as you looped from `len(pastResults)` to `index_I_really_need_now`.

Comment: You are correct. I removed the `not`. Appending does work for factorials and Fibonacci numbers, but not for problems 14, 74 and 92 of Project Euler. Profiling cannot reveal other factors and results may be different for other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer to the question regarding the performance, rather a general tip about caching previously calculated values. The usual way to do this is to use a map (Python `dict`) for this, as this allows to use more complex keys instead of just integer numbers, like floating point numbers, strings, or even tuples. Also, you won't run into problems in case your keys are rather sparse.

```
pastResults = {}
def someCalculation(integerArgument):
    if integerArgument not in pastResults:
        pastResults[integerArgument] = # calculation performed on numberArg.
    return pastResults[integerArgument]
```

Also, there is no need to perform the calculations "in order" using a loop. Just call the function for the value you are interested in, and the `if` statement will take care that, when invoked recursively, the function is called only once for each argument.

Ultimately, if you are using this a lot (as clearly the case for Project Euler) you can define yourself a [function decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary), like this one:

```
def memo(f):
    f.cache = {}
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        if args not in f.cache:
            f.cache[args] = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return f.cache[args]
    return _f
```

What this does is: It takes a function and defines another function that first checks whether the given parameters can be found in the cache, and otherwise calculates the result of the original function and puts it into the cache. Just add the `@memo` annotation to your function definitions and this will take care of caching for you.

```
@memo
def someCalculation(integerArgument):
    # function body
```

This is syntactic sugar for `someCalculation = memo(someCalculation)`. Note however, that this will not always work out well. First, the paremters have to be hashable (no lists or other mutable types); second, in case you are passing parameters that are not relevant for the result (e.g., debugging stuff etc.) your cache can grow unnecessarily large, as *all* the parameters are used as the key.